# Mostrar resultado JSON via Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, api

Não tenho muito conhecimento em javascript, mas preciso fazer a integração de uma API de pagamento.

Nunca realizei integrações com alguma API antes.

Seguindo a documentação vi que precisa primeiro gerar um token de transação.

Então tenho esse código:

```
function GeraToken() {
    var base64 = $.encodeBASE64(AppKey:CHAVE, Signature:ASSINATURA);

$.ajax({
    url: "http://desenvolvimento.intermeio.com/api/v2_1/Token/Gerar",
    headers: { "Authorization": "Intermeio " + base64, Content-Type: application/json },
    type: "POST",
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: "json",

    success: function () {
        alert('FOI');
    },
    error: function (xhr, status) {
        alert('NAO FOI');
    }
});
}
```

Onde a funcao GeraToken() é um botão que chama.

Mas eu queria ter a certeza que esta correta a chamada.
Quando clico no botão ele nao me retorna nenhum dos dois alerts. O mais ideal seria me retornar na tela mesmo o token, só pra eu ver mesmo que funcionou, porque eu preciso armazenar esse token  na base de dados.
Na API diz que o retorno será em JSON.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Grato desde ja!

Comment: Se ele não retorna nenhum dos dois alerts, ele provavelmente não está executando este ajax. Confirma a execução observando a aba "Network" na "Ferramente de Desenvolvedor" do seu navegador, ou coloca um alert/console.log antes de executar o ajax para ter certeza que ele passou por alí

Comment: No console aparece a mensagem:
 
Uncaught ReferenceError: GeraToken is not defined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick
 
 
O estranho é que se eu apagar tudo da função GeraToken() e deixar só um alert() dentro dela, somente para ver se entra na função. Aí o alert() é executado.
Mas se eu colocar o código ajax ele da esse erro no console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá,

Pelo que analisei e o que você colocou no comentário, sua função provavelmente está com falha de sintaxe. Parece que na propriedade "headers", a sub-propriedade "content-type" e seu valor estão sem aspas, tente assim:

```
function GeraToken() {
    var base64 = $.encodeBASE64(AppKey:CHAVE, Signature:ASSINATURA);

$.ajax({
    url: "http://desenvolvimento.intermeio.com/api/v2_1/Token/Gerar",
    headers: { "Authorization": "Intermeio " + base64, "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    type: "POST",
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: "json",

    success: function () {
        alert('FOI');
    },
    error: function (xhr, status) {
        alert('NAO FOI');
    }
});
}
```

Comment: Fiz dessa forma, mas cai na funcao de erro. O estranho é que quando faço teste no REST client usando essas mesmas credenciais ele retorna status 200. :/

Comment: Antes de eu testar dessa forma que mencionou ele estava mostrando erro no hífen do Content-Type, porque estava sem as aspas... de qualquer forma sua resposta ajudou. Muito obrigado!!